# how to reformat files with an emacs script

Tags: xml, emacs, indentation

I have a large number of XML files generated from a python script. The indentation is not as it should be and I open the file in Emacs, `C-x h`, `TAB`, `C-x C-s`, `C-x k`.
Is there a way to script this? In other words I want to use the emacs tab, which indents the entire selection on all XML files in a folder.

I tried getting the indentation right with Element.tail in the python script, but could not get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to write a function that reformats the current buffer, the way that you do it manually. For that, you need to find out the commands that the various key sequences you type are bound to. `C-h c` can be used for that, e.g. typing `C-h c C-x h` tells you that the command it's bound to is `mark-whole-buffer`. Once you've done that, then writing a function to automate the sequence is easy:

```
(defun reformat-buffer ()
   "Reformat the current buffer"
   (interactive)
   (mark-whole-buffer)
   (indent-for-tab-command)
   (save-buffer))
```

You can bind the function to some key sequence, but since I'm going to use this function within another function that loops over files, I won't bother. I also don't include a `(kill-buffer)` (the function bound to `C-x k`) here, since I'll be using a temporary buffer in the looping function.

The next step is to loop over all the files. You don't give any information on how the files are organized, so I'm going to make an assumption in order to write down something concrete: depending on how the files are organized, you might have to modify this.

I assume that all the files are in a single directory and have an `.xml` suffix.
We can then do the equivalent of `ls *.xml` to get all the files to operate on:

```
(defun reformat-files ()
   "Loop over all the files with suffix `.xml' in the current directory
    and apply the reformat-buffer function to each of them."
   (interactive)
   (dolist (file (directory-files "." nil "\.xml$")
      (with-temp-buffer
         (find-file file)
         (reformat-buffer))))
```

Assuming you are in the right directory (do `M-x cd` to make sure), you can execute this with `M-x reformat-files`.

There is no error handling at all here and there is no warranty either: make sure that you have copies of any files that cannot be regenerated easily.